# How to use Postgres jsonb '?' operator in Laravel with index support?

Tags: php, json, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm trying to use the jsonb exists operator '?' in Laravel's query builder, and have it use an index, but I've run into some issues.

Sample query

`DB::table('table_name')->whereRaw("jsonb_column ? 'key'")->get();`

Sample Index

`CREATE INDEX ON table_name USING GIN(jsonb_column jsonb_ops)`

The main issue seems to be that '?' is reserved for parameter replacement, so this query returns a syntax error. I've found a couple ways around this, but each are incomplete solutions.

1. *use '??' (a way to escape the ?)* `->whereRaw("jsonb_column ?? 'key'")`

   - doesn't work with querybuilder. returns `SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ?? unknown`
   - works with raw queries, e.g. `DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE jsonb_column ?? 'key'")`, but I need it to work with the query builder.
2. *use a named function / create an alias for the operator*

   - '?' translates to the function - jsonb_exists(jsonb, text)

     - `->whereRaw("jsonb_exists(jsonb_column, 'key')")`
   - `CREATE OPERATOR @-> ( PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists, LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text );`

     - `->whereRaw("jsonb_column @-> 'key'")`
   - these solutions both "work"... but they don't use indexes

Right now I'm researching `CREATE OPERATOR CLASS`, as a way to get my custom operator to use gin indexing, but it's a bit over my head. If anybody can give me some tips on how to accomplish this or, even better, some simpler solution, it'd be a huge help.

## edit

- using php 7.3

Comment: "doesn't work with querybuilder": What does the query builder look like? What's your PHP version?

Comment: Sorry thought it was self explanatory. Just replacing '?' with '??'. so ->whereRaw("jsonb_column ?? 'key'"), and I'm using PHP version 7.3

Comment: I was asking because I was surprised that `??` works with a raw query for you. As far as I know, `??` should only work on PHP 7.4: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pdo_escape_placeholders Can you upgrade? On PHP 7.4, I've successfully used `??` with the query builder.

Comment: holy $#!# it works. Upgrading to PHP 7.4 and then using a whereRaw with "??" works!! I love you, where is the upvote button?

Comment: You want to post a reply so I can give you credit for the solution? Otherwise I guess I'll just reply to myself to close the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP 7.4 allows you to escape the placeholder with `??`: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pdo_escape_placeholders

```
DB::table('table_name')->whereRaw('jsonb_column ?? ?', ['key'])->get();
```