# Eloquent ORM does not allow ? operator used in JSONB lookup

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, orm

Is it possible to run this postgres query with Eloquent ORM?

```
select * from "table" where "column"->'key' ? '1'
```

It throws error for using `?` in the query. Is there any alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_exists` function. All question marks determines as placeholder for prepared statements.

Or in php 7.4 you can use `??` (answer here: [How to use Postgres jsonb '?' operator in Laravel with index support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310077/how-to-use-postgres-jsonb-operator-in-laravel-with-index-support))

Answer (score 1):

Use a raw query instead:

```
DB::raw(" select * from \"table\" where \"column\"->'key' ? '1' ");
```

Comment: It throws error, can't use ? in any sort of queries with ORM.

Comment: I know Eloquent supports postgresql. What is the exact error log? Use `dd( exception here )` to diagnose it better